# Collecting and rechecking luggage in Doha- do I need a travel visa?

Tags: doha

Do I need a transit visa to collect and check luggage at Doha?

I bought a flight through doha on SkyPicker.  Though both flights are with Qatar airlines, the emailed itinerary insists I will need to collect and check my luggage in Doha.  This did surprise me.

As a US citizen I believe I will qualify for a travel visa with proof of return travel if necessary.  But I wonder if I will need them to collect my luggage and re-check them?  I have a little less than 4 hours between flights.

If I need a travel visa, I believe there is a fee of 40 pounds.  Can I pay in US dollars, and what should I bring?  Should I just get the visa there or do it online?

(after some review I see that using SkyPicker was/is a mistake.  I thought I tried comparing prices purchasing the tickets directly, but after rechecking I must have searched incorrectly misjudging skypicker.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luggage can be collected by flyer only after clearing immigration and thus by buying visa. Fees is QAR 100 (USD = 100/~3.65), and can br paid only by card ( any, debit/credit, which will work with visa/mastercard etc networks) no cash allowed.

Source: I live in Doha.

Edit: The only certain thing is, if airline does the transfer of luggage from one leg to other, then you don't need visa. If you, a.k.a Flyer need to collect it & then check it in for next leg, then you need visa.

Most probably if you get all the boarding passes at the start of your journey, most of the times it means your luggage is checked through all the way, and airline itself will do the luggage handling at transit airports.

Comment: If both legs of the flight have the same booking code, is it safe to believe luggage will be checked through?  I am receiving conflicting advice (email claims I will need to collect and recheck, online rep claims it will be passed through.  Online reviews indicate the company is unreliable).

Comment: I would trust email more, as some companies' online reps says just anything to get the customer off theback. Like Willeke said, try to ask at check-in, of they print your luggage tags with final destination, you are good.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the embassy in the US, and they mentioned if I have to collect the luggage in Doha, I will have to get a transit visa.